# How to open a document in Xpages mobile controls from an URL

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

How do I open a document in XPages mobile controls from a URL?

My application notifies users about pending review using an embedded URL link in an email. The requirement is to open the document in mobile controls (SinglePage/App Page). As of now I get a grey page on ipad when the link is clicked from the email.

However I am able to edit the same document using a button and `<moveTo>` tag. The following is a sample URL when loaded to a browser renders a grey page.

```
http://175.x.y.z/db.nsf/MN.xsp#newRequest&docId=123761231653&action=openDocument
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The #newRequest part of the URL needs to be moved to the END of the url string. Nothing after the # symbol in a URL is transfered to the server so the server never gets the docId or action parameters.

Comment: This was a bug in the ExtLib, I've since fixed it and it will be in the next release on openNTF, in particular addressing the issue where "&resetContent=true" is used after the hash for mobile pages only and this was causing the same issue with a grey page when trying to link to it from outside the app. Just FYI as it will make some actions easier